# Simple Button Program Aberration

Tags: button, arduino

I am trying to program 2 buttons (w/ an Arduino), one which will start a 5 second cycle and one which can stop the cycle at any point within this time frame.  When the "Start" button is pressed "START" is printed to the serial monitor, and if the cycle is allowed to complete, "DONE" will be printed as well, followed by a new line.  If the "stop" button is pressed, "STOP" is printed to the serial monitor and the cycle is terminated.  At least, in theory this is how it should work.  What I'm finding is that after I press the start button about 5 times, even if both buttons function perfectly beforehand, at this point the "DONE" will never be printed to the serial monitor.  The last thing printed will be the "START" from the most recent button press.  The only way to end this is to press the "stop" button, which prints "STOP."  However, after pressing the "start" button after this, the code prints a rapid succession of "START\nDONE" couplets.  Can anyone see a problem with the code I have?  I thought it was a pretty straightforward task, and maybe it's just a problem with the hardware, but if it is a problem with the code, I can't see it.

```
int startPin = 4;
int stopPin = 7;
int motorPin = 2;
boolean startState = false;
boolean stopState = false;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(startPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(stopPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("setup");
}

void loop()
{
  startState = digitalRead(startPin);
  if(startState == false)
  {
    return;
  }
 Serial.print("START\n");
 int time = millis() + 5000;
 while(millis() < time)
 {
   stopState = digitalRead(stopPin);
   if(stopState == true) {
     Serial.print("STOP\n");
     return;
   }
   analogWrite(motorPin, 255);
 }
 analogWrite(motorPin, 0);
 Serial.print("DONE\n\n");
}
```

As a final note- this is my first time using Stack Overflow, so I apologize in advance if this isn't a good question, or if it's already been answered, or if I'm doing something else that will appear overwhelmingly stupid to someone more experience than me.  And thank you to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

To start, change

```
int time = millis() + 5000;
```

To

```
unsigned long time = millis() + 5000;
```

millis() returns an unsigned long so if you are trying to insert that number + 5000 into a signed int, you are overflowing the int and causing weird calculations in your loop.